# Why do some of my normals look like this?

Tags: normals

Shouldnt everything be a solid blue color?

https://imgur.com/a/TydAYAZ
https://imgur.com/a/0bGhp0N

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Are youtalking about the bad shading? It's not a question about normals but about split normals (shading), it can be caused by ngons for example, but maybe share your file

Comment: The _Face Orientation_ only has two options to show the normals: they are either blue (the "front" or "outside" of the face) or red (the "back" or "inside" of the face). To me none of them look red. Smooth or flat shading is based on normals and geometry and would most likely also show up without overlaying the _Face Orientation_, but the simple orientation info itself is either blue or red.

Comment: sorry about the images on the other site, i already had the images uploaded and didnt know your able to uplaod images.

Comment: thank you to everyone who has tried to provide me with help.  it ended up being i had moved some vertices by accident causing the issue.  i havent really had much of an issue with this until recently. i try to remember to recalculate the normals when needed but this time i started this particular object over a few times and had the exact same issue.  its is probably due to my improper techniques all too often.  thank you for providing me with the best help that you were able to!!

Answer (score 1):

The blue and red colors are the *Face Orientation* colors set in the preferences. They are not fully opaque as shown in the screenshot below which means you will be able to see through them. If you don't want to see through them, you can set their *Alpha* value to 1.0.

[image: Face Orientation]

The shading artifacts visible in your screenshot have to do with the normals. They can usually be fixed by selecting the problematic vertices and running *Mesh > Normals > Reset Vectors* or *Mesh > Normals > Smooth Vectors* depending on your needs.